# Reshaping the input for LSTM networks in Tensorflow 1.13 and Keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

[image]

Here is a sample picture of the data 
I have 3000 samples (ID Column)  and 88 features ( total columns). In that number of feature columns, I have 20 columns called X's etc. For each one of them, I have 3 columns Xlag1, Xlag2, Xlag3 etc. as lag columns. T

Points of note 
-> It is a pandas dataframe 
-> The series are of varying sequence length so converting to lag windows helps even out sequence length
-> All the required historical data is in one data row

Now I want to feed it into an LSTM network -

How to convert that into a shape of 3D array to feed as input to LSTM model in tensorflow?

We are trying reshape ( 1 * 4 * number of features ). But do not know if that is the right way to go

I have read many articles. But I am a little confused.

Comment: Please put some sample of data or describe it

Comment: what type of model you want to use , what is your LSTM input size ? can you elaborate some more ?

Comment: it should be `[batch_size, time_steps, number_of_features]`. If you use Tensorflow, you can use Tensorflow Data API using [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) to reshape and feed the data directly into the model. Numpy also has the same titled function.